# Wind in "They're going through a tight wind"

Tags: pronunciation, lyrics

I'm a bit confused about the pronunciation and meaning of wind,
in the song Bltizkrieg Bop

there is this line:

> "They're going through a tight **wind**"

I hear it pronounced "waɪnd" like in the verb.
But I read that the meaning should be the noun wind.
Is it me, not hearing it well or it has a different meaning?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me. Poetry and lyrics often stretch the meanings of words. If you're sure it is "wind" pronounced /waɪnd/, I would guess that they are using it to mean "something that has been tightly wound", but it is not usually used in that way.

Comment: In this case, they're talking about riding somewhere in a car and the road has a tight curve, as in, "a long, and winding road."  ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about lyrics interpretation.

Comment: Note: the phrase first appears in a song by reggae great Junior Murvin, and reggae's adoption of Jamaican "pidgin" English dialect makes many such phrases hard to translate directly.

Answer (score 1):

I love this song!

A "tight wind" is not common in most English.  It's "wind" as in "winding a thread around a stick", and not the homonym "wind" as in "a cool wind is blowing".

The sense of it is that the subject is under stress or pressure in a bad or undesirable situation.

It's slang, and perhaps even possibly vulgar or even offensive (similar to and possibly derived from a vulgar expression involving the male genitalia - though I am not certain of the etymology.)